# how to use color selected from color dialog be used as brush color for printing

Tags: .net, vb.net, brush, colordialog

I need to know how to use the color that the user has chosen from a color dialog to create a brush so that it can print in color

Please help i've been at it for days yet still nothing

Comment: If you've been at this for days, you should have some code to show us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to get the color selected by the user and convert this into the appropriate brush:

```
    Dim userColor As Color = Color.Black 'set to a default color
    Using dlg As New ColorDialog
        dlg.Color = userColor
        If dlg.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            'user selected something (and clicked ok)
            userColor = dlg.Color
        End If
    End Using

    Using userBrush As New SolidBrush(userColor)
        'use the brush here
    End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim col as Color = Colors.Red
Dim bru as SolidColorBrush = New SolidColorBrush(col)
```